# How to convert a structure with dynamic length array member to byte[]?

Tags: c#, struct, arrays, marshalling

I have a struct like this:

```
    struct test
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
        public byte[] a;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
        public string b;
    }
```

and the member `a` size is dynamic which means i can't write the `SizeConst` in `MarshalAs` attribute.
**And here is the problem:**
When i try to convert it to `byte[]` like this:

```
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(t);

    byte[] bs = new byte[size];

    IntPtr pt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(t, pt, false);
    Marshal.Copy(pt, bs, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pt);
```

The `size` is 201 and the correct size is 212,so the result `byte[]` is wrong.It only has the first element in `t.a`.

Then I tried to make the size correct like this:

```
 int size = Marshal.SizeOf(t);
 size += t.a.Length - 1;
```

But even the `size` is right,the result `byte[]` is still wrong,how can I make the result correct?

Comment: When you use UnmanagedType.ByValArray then you *must* also use SizeConst.  It must match the size of the array in your native code declaration.

Comment: Thank you @Hans Passant,so if the array length can't be sure in design,it can't be solved?Or there is another `UnmanagedType` can be use on a dynamic length array?

Comment: It doesn't need to be solved, such a struct isn't usable in unmanaged code either.  Talk to the programmer whose code you are supposed to interop with.

Comment: All right,thank for advice Hans Passant.